# How to print all play framework crash?

Tags: playframework

I am using play framework v2.0.3.

I need to know how to see all the system log. 
For example, missing dependence jars,throw exception, etc.
what I see is that it just stuck or web socket get stuck after decoding .

I'm using logback as a logger.

This is the `logger.xml`

```xml
<configuration>

    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <!-- encoders are assigned the type ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder 
            by default -->
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
     <file>${application.home}/logs/application.log</file>
     <encoder>
       <pattern>%date - [%level] - from %logger in %thread %n%message%n%xException%n</pattern>
     </encoder>
   </appender>

   <logger name="play" level="ERROR" />
   <logger name="application" level="ERROR" />

    <root level="ERROR">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use DEBUG log level, don't you see exceptions in console?

Comment: I don't see the exceptions in the console it just get stuck with no log.